# Populate a WPF Combobox from Service

Tags: c#, wpf, web-services, xaml, combobox

I am trying to populate my combobox from a service response. The service returns an array of object like following

```
MyService.FirmSocial[] firmSocialList = client.GetActiveSocialMediaTypes();
```

I have checked, the firmSocialList populates properly. I need to populate my combobox with these values.

I have tried this in my code behind

```
cbSocialMediaTypes.ItemsSource = firmSocialList;
cbSocialMediaTypes.DisplayMemberPath = "socialMediaValue";
cbSocialMediaTypes.SelectedValuePath = "socialMediaType";
```

I also tried the same thing on the XAML side, but all I am getting is bunch of empty strings in my combobox. The thing is though, the number of elements matches with the item count of the combobox (of empty strings).

And yes, the property names of the FirmSocial object is correct.

The FirmSocial class

```
public class FirmSocial
{
    private int socialMediaType;
    private string socialMediaValue;
    public int SocialMediaType
    {
        get
        {
            return socialMediaType;
        }
        set
        {
            socialMediaType = value;
        }
    }
    public string SocialMediaValue
    {
        get
        {
            return socialMediaValue;
        }
        set
        {
            socialMediaValue = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And I have also tried this in my XAML section;

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbSocialMediaTypes" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="56,8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="211"
ItemsSource="{Binding firmSocialList}"
DisplayMemberPath="socialMediaType"
SelectedValuePath="socialMediaType" />
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please avoid artificially adding tags to your question titles.  See [What are tags, and how should I use them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging).

Comment: Can you post a little snippet of the properties in FirmSocial? One thing I notice is with C# the convention is to have property names capitalised and fields lower case. That would suggest socialMediaValue is a field not a property (though obviously, this is only the convention).

Also, are there any binding errors in the output (though I'm not sure the member paths produce binding errors)

Comment: Hi @Joe I have added the FirmSocial class content. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong actually, I am fairly new to WPF... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DisplayMemberPath is case sensitive.

```
DisplayMemberPath="socialMediaType"
```

is saying trying to bind to your private field, not your public property. Try:

```
DisplayMemberPath="SocialMediaType"
```

Comment: That was embarrassing! I didn't even notice... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you set the [DisplayMemberPath](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwib1K-__YbMAhWOJhoKHWsnChYQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNF6qnwMzrhXZPu4xqTt6HbcX_Geqw&bvm=bv.119028448,d.ZWU&cad=rja) and the [SelectedValuePath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath(v=vs.110).aspx) to a private fields instead of a public properties.

```
cbSocialMediaTypes.DisplayMemberPath = "socialMediaValue";
cbSocialMediaTypes.SelectedValuePath = "socialMediaType";
```

Change it to

```
cbSocialMediaTypes.DisplayMemberPath = "SocialMediaValue";
cbSocialMediaTypes.SelectedValuePath = "SocialMediaType";
```